# enctype and file upload

Tags: php, file-upload, enctype

> i made a form page to upload files

`<form role="form" action="portfilio.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/from-data">` 
`<textarea class="form-control textarea" name="desc"></textarea>`  
`<input type="file" name= "img" class="custom-file-input" id="exampleInputFile">`

> when i want to test it if he is working or not by using this code

`if (isset($_POST['desc'])) { echo '<pre>'; print_r($_FILES);die; }`

> should send somthing like
> [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fK6C.png)
> but not just empty array like :
> `Array ()`
> but why ? where the wrong ??

Comment: Question: Are you using POST method ? (not GET)

Comment: You're sending the form via the `POST` method, so you should use `print_r($_POST);` to get the textarea value and use `print_r($_FILES);` to get the uploaded files.

Comment: sorry i published my test cases not my main code XO

Comment: now i edit it, and `print_r($_FILES);` not working so im asking here

Comment: finally  `print_r($_POST); ` sending me this and this not what i want`Array
(
    [desc] => 
    [files] => 
    [img] => 
)`

Comment: You also have a typo here: `enctype="multipart/from-data"`, should be `form` instead of `from`.

Comment: what a hack its work !! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Please fix the typo and use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

(2) Please use $_POST and $_FILES to get the submitted data details, as follows:

```
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
```

So , amend your code to

HTML

```
<form  action="test1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
<textarea class="form-control textarea" name="desc"></textarea>

<input type="file" name= "img" class="custom-file-input" id="exampleInputFile">
<input type=submit>
```

and

test1.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['desc'])) { 

print_r($_POST);
echo "<br>";
print_r($_FILES);

//die; 
}

?>
```

The result (if you type something in the textarea and pick a file, then submit) will be like (**well tested**):

```
Array ( [desc] => Test1 Test2 )
Array ( [img] => Array ( [name] => 2.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpO9vL4C [error] => 0 [size] => 22904 ) )
```

Comment: thnx , its work i appreciate all this

Answer (score 0):

try running. print_r($_POST);

It will show all the post output also sometime editing a template creates some problem so you have to do it with care.

Comment: the `print_r($_POST);` never help bcz i want some data about the file before moving it so acttuly using  `print_r($_FILES);` to know what the file name rename it and move to upload directory

Comment: finally `print_r($_FILES);` not work when i checking the array i found it empty

Comment: You can also print $_FILES also if you are not getting data, you must check all the closing tags of your template. also form tag are closed at the right position. Also check that input type is submit for the button